# UserDefaults(suiteName:) not propagating between app and extension

Tags: swift, userdefaults

While both my app and extension are able to see and read/write to my shared UserDefaults object, accessed in both cases via:

```
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.markl.wrshared.container") {
   ...
}
```

...they can only read data values that they have written themselves (Strings, in both cases). For example, if I try to read a value from the extension saved by the app:

```
preferredLanguage = userDefaults.string(forKey: "language")
```

I always get `nil`, but I can read `userDefaults` values perfectly well in the extension that were written to userDefaults in the extension. And the same is true going the other way: can't read values from the app that were written by the extension, but can read ones written by the app.

To me it seems obvious that I must be actually writing to different `UserDefaults` objects, but I have done many iterations of changing the group name, the `App Groups` listing in each target's *Signing and Capabilities* section, making sure to use `UserDefaults.synchronize()` etc. If they really are writing to different `UserDefaults` objects I'm at a loss to explain.

I'd be very grateful for any solutions or ideas for how to troubleshoot the problem!

Comment: App Group must be the same for the app and the extension, and you must use the group name as `suiteName` as well.

Comment: Argh, I'm stupid. Also, I wish I'd asked sooner--many hours have been lost :)

Comment: To me it wasn't obvious that the App Group is the same as the suiteName; my App Group was named group.markl.wrshared and I added a .container for my suiteName. So this means that an App Group may only contain one UserDefaults object?

Comment: @storoj, please add this as an answer, as I spent 1 day to find this.

Comment: @DisplayName done, no idea why did I comment back then

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired behaviour the App Group must be the same for both the app and the extension, and you must use that name as `suiteName`.